# Neural Network Continuous Perceptron Error Function

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks

Let $u={\bf w}^{\text T}{\bf x}$ and $o=f(u)$.  Can someone explain to me step by step how the partial derivative below was obtained?  Thank you.
$$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\partial E({\bf w})}{\partial{\bf w}} & = & \frac12\frac{\partial(d-o)^2}{\partial{\bf w}}\\
& = & -(d-o)\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial{\bf w}}\\
& = &-(d-o)\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial{\bf w}}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: to be honest, i not very sure how to interpret the question. I know how to differentiate it but i don understand the concept of it. 

if i am not wrong, the "u" mean (d - o) right?

Comment: I deleted my comment above, because I used confusing notation.  See my answer below.

Comment: I've edited your question and replaced the image with MathJax.  You should do this next time; images take longer to download and are not searchable.  Read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to learn how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $d$ is a constant with respect to $\bf{w}$.

For the second line, use the fact that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}(d-o)^2=2(d-o)\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}(d-o)$.

Then use $\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}(d-o)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}d-\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}o=0-\frac{\partial}{\partial\bf{w}}f(u)$.

For the third line, use the chain rule.

Comment: ok, thank for your explanation and edit